# Doubly linked list code in C

Tags: c, linked-list

Let me know if it seems right to you and if anything can be optimized.

```
/* 
 * Doubly Linked List
 *
 * Each node of the list contain two references (or links) – one to the previous node and other to the next node.
 * The previous link of the first node and the next link of the last node points to NULL.
 * In comparison to singly-linked list, doubly-linked list requires handling of more pointers 
 * but less information is required as one can use the previous links to observe the preceding element.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
} Node;

void insert(Node *current, int data);
void delete(Node *current, int data);
void print(Node *current);
int find(Node *current, int data);

void insert(Node *current, int data) {

    // current is pointing to first element
    // we iterate until we find the end
    while(current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    // create a new Node and insert the item
    current->next = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (current->next)->prev = current;
    current = current->next;
    current->data = data;
    current->next = NULL;
}

void delete(Node *current, int data){

    // Iterate until we find a pointer next to the one we need to delete
    while (current->next != NULL && (current->next)->data != data) {
        current = current->next;
    }

    // Item is not found
    if(current->next == NULL) {
        printf("\nElement %d is not present in the list\n", data);
        return;
    }

    // The element is found in the node next to the one that current points to
    // We removed the node which is next to the pointer (which is also temp)
    Node *tmp = current->next;
    // In special case that we are deleting last node
    if(tmp->next == NULL) {
        current->next = NULL;
    } else {
        current->next = tmp->next;
        (current->next)->prev = tmp->prev;
    }
    tmp->prev = current;

    // We got rid of the node, now time to dellocate the memory
    free(tmp);

    return;
}
void print(Node *current) {
    while(current != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }   
}

int find(Node *current, int data) {
    // First pointer is head aka dummy node with no data
    // so we go to next one
    current = current->next;

    // Iterate through the linked list
    while(current != NULL) {
        if(current->data == data) {
            return 1;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {

    Node *head = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    head->next = NULL;
    head->prev = NULL;

    int data = 0;
    int usr_input = 0;

    while(1){
        printf("0. Exit\n");
        printf("1. Insert\n");
        printf("2. Delete\n");
        printf("3. Print\n");
        printf("4. Find\n");


        scanf("%d", &usr_input);

        // can also use a switch instead
        if( usr_input == 0) {
            exit(0);

        } else if(usr_input == 1) {
            printf("\nEnter an element you want to insert: ");
            scanf("%d", &data);
            insert(head, data);

        } else if(usr_input == 2) {
            printf("\nEnter an element you want to delete: ");
            scanf("%d", &data);
            delete(head, data);

        } else if(usr_input == 3) {
            printf("The list is ");
            print(head->next);
            printf("\n\n");

        } else if(usr_input == 4) {
            printf("\nEnter an element you want to find: ");
            scanf("%d", &data);
            int is_found = find(head, data);
            if (is_found) {
                printf("\nElement is found\n\n");
            } else {
                printf("\nElement is NOT found\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some mostly stylistic improvements you could apply:

- There is no need to cast the return value of `malloc()`, unless you plan on compiling this code as C++. In C, `void*` converts implicitly to any other pointer type. So the cast is just boilerplate in this case.
- Prefer using `sizeof(variable)` instead of `sizeof(Type)`. Example:

  ```
  Node *head = malloc(sizeof(*head));
  ```

  This makes maintenance easier, since now if you introduce a new `Node` type, you only have to change one place, with no chance of updating one side of the expression and forgetting the other. Note that in this example, the dereference of `head` is valid because `sizeof` is a compile-time operation, so there is no actual pointer access taking place here, just type inference.
- Consider giving more robust names to your functions. `find()`, `insert()`, etc, are very common names, which can apply to many things, not just lists. In C, you cannot overload function names, so in any major project, these names would be very likely to cause collisions with other global identifiers. Name prefixes are a common approach in C to solve this problem. Consider prefixing the function names with `list_` or any other prefix you might prefer. I.e.:

  ```
  void list_insert(Node *current, int data);
  void list_delete(Node *current, int data);
  ```
- Instead of returning an integer 0|1 to represent a boolean value, you can use the `bool` type, declared in the [`<stdbool.h>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdbool/) header, which is more idiomatic.
- `delete()` function is a void function, so it doesn't need an explicit return statement at the end.
- Looks like you are using `printf()` to log errors:

  > ```
  > if(current->next == NULL) {
  >     printf("\nElement %d is not present in the list\n", data);
  >     return;
  > }
  > ```

  For error output, it is more correct to use fprintf and write to the [`stderr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stderr/?kw=stderr) standard stream.
- The list printing function `print()` could be made more flexible by receiving the output stream as a parameter. So you don't limit the caller to always printing to `stdout`, it can also be used to dump the list to a file (notice the use of [`fprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/)).

  ```
  void print(Node *current, FILE *stream) {
      while(current != NULL) {
          fprintf(stream, "%d ", current->data);
          current = current->next;
      }   
  }
  ```
- When you want to allocate and immediately zero-initialize data, such as in here:

  > ```
  > Node *head = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  > head->next = NULL;
  > head->prev = NULL;
  > ```

  The standard function [`calloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/) can be used to make code more concise:

  ```
  Node *head = calloc(1, sizeof(*head));
  ```

Comment: Why the pointless parentheses in `sizeof(variable)` instead of simply `sizeof variable`?  That looks too much like `sizeof (type)` for my liking.

Answer (score 4):

```
void insert(Node *current, int data);
void delete(Node *current, int data);
void print(Node *current);
int find(Node *current, int data);
```

As written, you don't need these.  The definition can serve as a declaration as well.

```
// current is pointing to first element
// we iterate until we find the end
```

You can avoid this with

```
typedef struct DoublyLinkedList {
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *tail;
} DoublyLinkedList;
```

Then `insert` can be

```
void insert(DoublyLinkedList list, int data) {
    // create a new Node and insert the item
    list.tail->next = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (list.tail->next)->prev = list.tail;
    list.tail = list.tail->next;
    list.tail->data = data;
    list.tail->next = NULL;
}
```

You also might want to consider calling that `append` rather than `insert`.  To me, `insert` implies that it could be at the beginning or in the middle.  In fact, my first thought was that you'd insert at the beginning of the list.

Alternately, you could also just make `head` into a `root` node.

```
Node *root = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
root->next = root;
root->prev = root;
```

This is hackier but allows for

```
void insert(Node *root, int data) {
    // create a new Node and insert the item
    (root->prev)->next = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    ((root->prev)->next)->prev = root->prev;
    root->prev = (root->prev)->next;
    (root->prev)->data = data;
    (root->prev)->next = root;
}
```

But you have to change the other functions to match.  E.g.

```
void delete(Node *root, int data) {
    Node *current = root;

    // Iterate until we find a pointer next to the one we need to delete
    while ( current->next != root && (current->next)->data != data ) {
        current = current->next;
    }

    // Item is not found
    if ( current->next == root ) {
        printf("\nElement %d is not present in the list\n", data);
        return;
    }

    // The element is found in the node next to the one that current points to
    // We removed the node which is next to the pointer (which is also temp)
    Node *tmp = current->next;

    current->next = tmp->next;
    (current->next)->prev = tmp->prev;

    // We got rid of the node, now time to deallocate the memory
    free(tmp);
}
```

I found

```
    tmp->prev = current;
```

Which is unnecessary as the next step is to free `tmp`.

```
    return;
```

This is also unnecessary.  The function will return naturally at the end.  You only need to use `return` if you want to leave early.

```
int find(Node *current, int data) {
```

Why not

```
Node * find(Node *current, int data) {
```

Then you can get the true or false result by something like

```
if ( NULL != find(root, value) ) {
```

Then you can implement `delete` as

```
Node *location = find(root, value);
if ( NULL != location ) {
    delete(location);
}
```

With definition:

```
void delete(Node *current) {
    (current->prev)->next = current->next;
    (current->next)->prev = current->prev;

    // We got rid of the node, now time to deallocate the memory
    free(current);
}
```

Or stick with the original method signature:

```
void delete(Node *root, int data) {
    Node *current = find(root, value);

    // Item is not found
    if ( NULL == current ) {
        printf("\nElement %d is not present in the list\n", data);
        return;
    }

    (current->prev)->next = current->next;
    (current->next)->prev = current->prev;

    // We got rid of the node, now time to deallocate the memory
    free(current);
}
```

Note that if you removed the separate declarations, you would want to move `find` above `delete` in the code.

```
return 0;
```

This would never be reached and is unnecessary in `main`.  The compiler will add it for you.

Answer (score -3):

You are changing the head pointer in all the function. You should copy that to a temp pointer and traverse it.